# Data/model managing in React Router / Redux application

Tags: reactjs, data-structures, redux, data-management

I'm wondering what the best approach is to load server data in a React application which uses `React Router` and `Redux`.
For example: When accessing `/dossier/123` I only want to retrieve data for that particular dossier. When navigating to /dossiers, I want to show "some" data about all items (title, description, owner, ...).
This means, that my model would look something like this:

```
{
    dossiers: IDossier[];
}

interface IDossier {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    owner: IUser;
    codes?: ICode[];
    template?: ITemplate;
}
```

When "entering" the application at /dossier/123, the "initial" state would look like

```
{
    dossiers: [{
        id: 123,
        title: "My dossier",
        description: "...",
        owner: { id: 1; name: "John Doe" },
        codes: [{ ... }, { ... }],
        template: { ... }
    }]
}
```

However when entering at /dossiers, the initial state would look more like

```
{
    dossiers: [{
        id: 123,
        title: "My dossier",
        description: "...",
        owner: { id: 1; name: "John Doe" }
    }, {
        id: 456,
        title: "Another dossier",
        description: "...",
        owner: { id: 2; name: "Jane Doe" }
    }, {
        ...
    }]
}
```

When *then* navigating to /dossier/123 or /dossier/456, I need some kind of indication I have to load the codes and template info, since they are not yet fetched - at least not the first time I would enter the url endpoint.

**So I guess my main question is**: how can I manage this in a robust way, without the need of re-fetching data when it's already available in the store, when navigating back and forth in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you need to have certain instance of dossiers loaded, or entire collection, you should first take a look at the data already in the store and determine if you need to make a call to the API or not. It’s up to you to decide. Some apps might refresh the data each time you open the page, and some might refresh at most once a day.

If there are multiple different collections of data having the same logic — for instance, arrays with objects having an `id` which are loaded at first and never refreshed — then you should probably make an abstraction of that logic, so that you don’t need to repeat yourself.

I would suggest using functional programming. More sprecifically, higher-order functions.

For instance, make a generic collection loader.

```
// Collection loader “constructor”.
const createCollectionLoader = (store, selector, actionPrefix) => {
  // Actual collection loader.
  return {
    // Function that makes sure collection is loaded.
    loadAll: () => {
      const collection = selector(store.getState());
      const shouldLoad = …; // Decide if it should load.
      if (shouldLoad) {
        store.dispatch({ type: `${actionPrefix}_LOAD`, data });
        try {
          const data = …; // Load.
          store.dispatch({ type: `${actionPrefix}_LOAD_SUCCESS`, data });
        } catch (error) {
          store.dispatch({ type: `${actionPrefix}_LOAD_ERROR`, error });
        }
      }
    },
    // Function that makes sure single collection item is loaded.
    load: (id) => {
      const collection = selector(store.getState());
      const item = collection.find(item => item.id === id);
      const shouldLoad = …; // Decide if it should load.
      if (shouldLoad) {
        store.dispatch({ type: `${actionPrefix}_ITEM_LOAD`, data });
        try {
          const data = …; // Load.
          store.dispatch({ type: `${actionPrefix}_ITEM_LOAD_SUCCESS`, data });
        } catch (error) {
          store.dispatch({ type: `${actionPrefix}_ITEM_LOAD_ERROR`, error });
        }
      }
    },
  };
};
```

And then for each collection you have, create loader.

```
const dossiersLoader = createCollectionLoader(store, state => state.dossiers, 'DOSSIERS');
```

Finally, every time you want to make sure dossiers (or single dossier is loaded), call adequate loader function.

```
dossiersLoader.loadAll();
// or
dossiersLoader.load(id)
```

To make it even better, introduce an abstraction representing unit of work — call it task, job, process, saga, etc.

I prefer splitting my React web application code into three distinct groups: UI, state, logic. And for that, I recommend using `react` (obviously), `react-redux`, and `redux-saga`, respectively. It is not uncommon to see many higher order components, sagas, and even reducers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @jokka. Although I was hoping for some more general pattern instead of the `// Decide if it should load` part :)

Comment: It is hard to generalize actual decision about data refreshing, because it varies a lot throughout the apps — depends on, for instance, do you have an explicit refresh button, is the data changing rapidly, etc. Also, sounds like you have already made up your mind about the logic. What was the question again? Should you skip loading or how to do it?